# RhoMobile: Lock portrait view

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, rhomobile, rhodes

I'm developing an application in RhoMobile which requires to display the content only in portrait view.

I've tried:

```
disable_screen_rotation = 1  //in rhoconfig.txt
```

and it does not work. I understand the line avobe only works in iPhone and Android, but it does not work for me.

I've also tried to modify 
Rhodes.java to:

```
this.setRequestedOrientation(disableScreenRotation ?
ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE :
ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
```

the problem is that I'm using Rhodes 3.4.1 and I can't find the location of Rhodes.java.
Can I accomplish this with JQM and CSS? (I don't think it is a good idea but I may be wrong.) 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why the downvote? Please explain so I can fix it. It is not constructive to downvote without a reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for this... I just modified rhodes/platform/android/Rhodes/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity" android:configChanges="portrait">
```

Answer (score 0):

1. For RhoMobile, both android and iphone, change your build.yml and add:

   ```
   android:
       orientation: portrait

   iphone:
       orientation: portrait
   ```
2. jQM with phonegap, just change android manifest and add (this wont work in RhoMobile):

   ```
   android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
   android:screenOrientation="landscape"
   ```

For iOs change Info.plist file, add the UIInterfaceOrientation key and set its value to the landscape mode.

What every you do in the end know that only successful way to achieve this is to change platform configuration files. RhoMobile will require you to change build.yml, you will be able to change platform config files but they will be rewritten at build state.